# Working out arms twice a day

Tags: muscle-gain, pull-ups, rest, resistancetraining

I guess working out the same muscle group twice a day may be a bad idea since it needs rest, but what about arms, considering they repair a lot faster?

Currently I can do only 5-6 pull ups and my arms tire way faster than when I feel it in my back or something.

So would training just pull ups, in addition to my regular morning workouts, in the evening be better than training once a day or every other day? Perhaps, I can try to fit a nap during the afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Any amount of working out is fine, so long as you provide your body adequate amounts of rest and nutrition. The more you workout, the more you need to eat and sleep.

We can't tell you how your body in particular needs to go about doing it, but it's not really a problem. Do it, and see what the results are.

If you feel fine and get stronger, then continue.

If you feel fatigued and get weaker, stop.